# Connectivity Issue with my R plumber API hosted on an EC2 Instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, plumber

I have a created an R plumber API that I host on an AWS EC2 instance, however the web developers at my Company that are trying to perform GET requests on my API are receiving a connectivity error. I am not sure why. Here's what they are running from their development server to try to get the data hosted at my API endpoints:

```
curl -X GET http://12.345.678.90:8003/path-to-endpoint
```

and here's what they're receiving...

```
About to connect() to 12.345.678.90 port 8003 (#0)  
Trying 12.345.678.90...   
Connection refused      
Failed connect to 12.345.678.90:8003; Connection refused
Closing connection 0
```

.
.

If I simply go to the endpoints in my local browser, or from any browser, then it works and is showing the data, but for some reason it's not connecting using curl program. To add, these same URL endpoints are working on the Company's production server, just not on their development server - so I'm not sure if my EC2 instance is simply not allowing access for the development server IP.

### How to Resolve

From the EC2 instance, I have tried to make custom TCP Rules to allow inbound 
connections from anywhere. My instance has the following inbound and outbound security rules:

[image]

and

[image]

Despite all this, the web developers at my company still cannot connect to get the API from my endpoint at http://12.345.678.90:8003/path-to-endpoint. Is there something I'm not doing that allows them to access the API?

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated!!

**Edit1**: This comment from the developers I'm working with - "If i use http URL from a local browser then it works and is showing the CSV, but for some reason it's not showing using curl program. We added 12.345.678.90 IP in our firewall also but still no luck."

**Edit2**: This is related to the topic but not directly related to the question - how can I allow public access / any access to my endpoint over https (rather than http). Even in my own local browser, I cannot access the endpoint at an https URL?

Thanks as always!

Comment: Did you consider a firewall (or proxy) that is installed at your office (not on local machines, but for your office network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a number of plumber APIs internally.

And typically, this is a firewall problem.

You can get those ports opened up. But then you're forced to go back to networking each time you want to offer a new service to ask them to open a new port.

But this is where a reverse proxy shines.

I use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/).

If you route your traffic to a new endpoint on port 80, you can have as many endpoints as you have ports (without ever having to go back and ask for more firewall).

**A working Example**

The following example configures an endpoint at:

http://12.345.678.90/myplumberapi/path-to-endpoint

This nginx.conf offers the service on port 80

(Note for nginx experts, there are probably some inefficiencies here, my apologies)

```
http {
        default_type application/json;
        sendfile   on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

        # note I only list one server here, but if you want
        # to serve your endpoints on more locations, change this
        upstream myplumberapi_pool {
                least_conn;
                server localhost:8003 weight=1;
        }


        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                default upgrade;
                ''      close;
        }

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen  [::]:80 default_server;
                location /myplumberapi/ {
                            access_log /var/log/nginx/app.log;
                            rewrite ^/myplumberapi/(.*)$ /$1 break;
                            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                            proxy_set_header Host $host;
                            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                            proxy_pass http://myplumberapi_pool;
                            proxy_read_timeout 20d;
                            proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500;
                    }

         }
}

events {
        worker_connections 4096;
}
```

You can add more APIs in the same way

---

***Response to EDIT:***

Regarding how to support https you need a certificate and a domain name (Can't do https from an IP), but if you have both then there are easy walkthroughs with nginx.

Comment: Thanks. I'll review nginx a bit and see if it's the right fit for my problem. Appreciate the input / help